# I am trying to create a login form but I am getting an error that is blocking the form from showing

Tags: php

I am trying to create a login form but issues this error and it blocking the form from showing

```
// Check if username is empty
if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
    $username_err = "Please enter username.";
} else{
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
}
```

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in
>   C:\UwAmp\www\form\login.php on line 22

Comment: What is line 22?

Comment: Which line is 22?

Comment: Please work on your question: "this error" is very bad for the title. Also remove the "enter code here".

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 4):

You're using an outdated version of PHP. Your problem is here:

```
if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
```

In versions prior to 5.5, `empty()` required a variable and didn't work with the return value of a function call. You have two options, you can update to a version of PHP that isn't end-of-lifed (preferred) or assign to a temp var:

```
$temp = trim($_POST["username"]);
if(empty($temp)){
```